# How do I append new element to existing xml using vtd-xml in java

Tags: java, xml, vtd-xml

Here is my current xml file,

```
<MainRoot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Root>      
    <RootElement name="rootelement1" date="21.Nov">
        <SubElement id="32"/>
    </RootElement>
    <RootElement name="rootelement2" date="1.Dec">
        <SubElement id="45"/>
    </RootElement>
    <RootElement name="rootelement3" date="18.Dec">
        <SubElement id="12"/>
    </RootElement>      
</Root>
```

I need a java code with vtd-xml parse to append a new RootElement tag with its SunElement tag
Here is my java code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    VTDGen vtdGenerator;
    VTDNav vtdNavigator;
    XMLModifier xmlModifier;
    AutoPilot autoPilot;
    vtdGenerator = new VTDGen();
    if (vtdGenerator.parseFile("test.xml", false)) {
        vtdNavigator = vtdGenerator.getNav();
        autoPilot = new AutoPilot(vtdNavigator);
        autoPilot.bind(vtdNavigator);
        autoPilot.selectElement("RootElement");
        xmlModifier = new XMLModifier();
        while (autoPilot.iterate()) {
            // code to insert new RootElement tag with its subElment tag and
            // their atributes
        }
    }
    xmlModifier.output(new FileOutputStream("test.xml"));
}
```

I can insert single tag using this

```
xmlModifier.insertAfterElement("<RootElement name=\"rootelement4\" date=\"21.Dec\">\n\t\t<SubElement id=\"66\"/>\n</RootElement>");
```

but I want to insert multiple RootElement tags which is now allowed by this process.
can anyone help me on this to append multiple tags to an xml. Is there any other approach to this.
I don't want to use DOM parser, as the order of attributes are not guaranteed with DOM.

I need output like this,

```
<MainRoot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Root>      
    <RootElement name="rootelement1" date="21.Nov">
        <SubElement id="32"/>
    </RootElement>
    <RootElement name="rootelement2" date="1.Dec">
        <SubElement id="45"/>
    </RootElement>
    <RootElement name="rootelement3" date="18.Dec">
        <SubElement id="12"/>
    </RootElement>      
    <RootElement name="rootelement4" date="21.Dec">
        <SubElement id="66"/>
    </RootElement>      
</Root>
```

Comment: Have you considered appending multiple RootElement to a single string, and then inserting that string into the existing XML as a single unit?

Comment: yes, this could be one approach to do this.Thanks @ vtd-xml-author.

Comment: How can I insert my new RootElement tag next to rootelement2 node? how can I iterate the cursor back and forth to point the exact location?

Comment: When you insert a new RootElement tag next to rootelement2 node, your cursor is probably at rootElement2, there is probably no need to iterate cursor cuz you are at it already... did I get your question right?

Comment: This is the statement am using to insert new element
xmlModifier.insertBeforeElement("Inserting new RootElement");
can I  insert element using node location as
vtdNavigator.pointCursorTo(int index); then perform insert operation xmlModifier.insertBeforeElement("Inserting new RootElement");

Comment: Then toElement(VTDNav.PrevSibling) would move the cursor back... remember that XMLModifier doesn't honor document change instantly, therefore the underlying vtd and indexing full reflect the  content and structure of the original document

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info. @ vtd-xml-author

Comment: I am gonna write up a formal response by combining some of the comments I gave, hope it is ok with you. I just want someone who has similar questions to be able to read a formal answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider appending multiple RootElement to a single string, and then inserting that string into the existing XML as a single unit. If you use insertBeforeElement, Then toElement(VTDNav.PrevSibling) would move the cursor back... remember that XMLModifier doesn't honor document change instantly, therefore the underlying vtd and indexing full reflect the content and structure of the original document.